# Use RTC periodic funktion (pass event handler)

Tags: c, function, pointers, events, event-handling

i want to use a periodic RTC function from a TTTech Library but i have problems 
to understand and use this function. How i can pass a function call (event_handler). What i must do with this parameter (event_handler).

IO_RTC_PeriodicInit ( ubyte2 period, rtc_eventhandler_ptr event_handler );

\brief Initializes the Periodic Timer

Initializes a periodic timer

\param  period              Period on which the event handler should be called.                          unit: us (500..65535)
 \param  event_handler       Function pointer to the periodic event handler

---

define IO_RTC_TICKS_PER_US  ((IO_DRIVER_SYSTEM_CLOCK) / 80)

typedef for function pointer for event handler of the periodic
interrupt handler
typedef void (*rtc_eventhandler_ptr) (void);

Does anyone have an idea to use the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own function, for example,

```
void maxxfunc(void)
{
  /* Do something here... */
}
```

Then pass it to the API,

```
IO_RTC_PeriodicInit (100000, maxxfunc );
```

That should call your function 10 times/second (once every 100000 us).

Comment: In other words, the `event_handler` parameter needs to have a type signature that matches the `rtc_eventhandler_ptr` typedef. It should return `void` and have parameter list `(void)`. The C syntax `(*func)` for function pointers is weird, but one gets used to it.